# Replace multiple elements of a list

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to redo the following (simplified) python example in Haskell

```py
zerosList = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for number in range(1,10):
  if (number & 1) == 0:
    for index in range(number,9,2):
      zerosList[index] = zerosList[index]+1
```

where we change some values in the list from `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` to `[0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0]`.

I suppose I have to use some `filter`s to capture even numbers and then probably use a `map` or a `foldl` somewhere... but can't figure out how to assemble the whole thing. Something like that?

```hs
zeros   = take 10 $ cycle [0]
numbers = [1..10]
foldl (+) zeros $ filter even numbers
```

or that?

```hs
zeros   = take 10 $ cycle [0]
numbers = [1..10]
map (+ $ filter even numbers) zeros
```

Well, none of that works so I am clearly on the wrong path. Maybe I should write a replaceAt function?

Comment: You can replace `take 10 $ cycle [0]` with `replicate 10 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way to get the output list you want is to observe that it is very predictable: it's just an interleaving of `[0..4]` and `repeat 0`.

```
concat $ zipWith (\a b -> [a, b]) [0..4] (repeat 0)
```

You may object that this isn't implementing your algorithm, it's making use of some insight into your simplification that doesn't exist in your real data. Well, too bad, I would say. Porting an imperative algorithm to a functional language often requires thinking about the problem differently. If my solution is too specialized to work for your real inputs, consider providing more realistic inputs.

Comment: Even simpler, `concat (map (\x -> [x, 0]) [0..4])` (ignoring `concatMap` and `>>=` for now).

Comment: (But +1 for the important point about thinking about the problem, not the particular algorithm.)

Comment: I am sure you are right about the functional programming thinking. Where can I found any resources out there to acquire this mindset?

Comment: @pid Practice, mostly. Or do exercises and read others' solutions to those exercises.

Comment: Alright. Then, where can I find good exercises to practice?

Comment: @pid There are many hits on Google for "haskell exercises". Exercism is popular, and seems fine. You can do exercises from previous years of Advent of Code.

Answer (score 1):

You may be overthinking this. When you understand how pattern-matching lists works, this becomes fairly straightforward.

```
replace :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
replace _ [] = []
replace i [x] = [i]
replace i (x:y:xs) = i : y : replace (i+1) xs
```

We can match an empty list, and that should obviously return an empty list. Since the pattern is every *even* index being replaced by an increasing number, starting at `0`, we know a list with a single element is just replaced by a list with that increasing int.

Now, we can also pattern match the first *two* elements of a list, and the tail. We simply replace the first one with the increasing int, don't modify the second, and cons it all onto the result of calling the function on the tail while increasing the int by one.

```
ghci> replace 0 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0]
```

Passing in the initial zero could be easily hidden.

```
replace :: [Int] -> [Int]
replace = replace' 0
  where 
    replace' _ [] = []
    replace' i [x] = [i]
    replace' i (x:y:xs) = i : y : replace' (i+1) xs
```